# AngularJS2 + Apache routing

Tags: apache, angular

I'm currently using Angular2 with Apache and I have a problem: when I use routing and navigate through pages,  template syntax doesn't work, I just get an empty space in the place where {{}} is in the template. Also ngOnInit seems to be not working. When I use lite-server everything works fine.
EDIT1: I'm trying to run an example from developer's guide on routing: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html 
https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html

EDIT2: I'm also using CodeIgniter 3 and it already uses the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Could you give us some details about the way you implemented routing in your Angular2 application? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks very much! Any error messages in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 1):

It could be an issue with redirects/not-found files.

Try adding `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN ServeStatic

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>

# END ServeStatic
```